# fetching value for given string

Tags: java

I want to search for a string and fetch the value for that string in a file .
For example file contains something like this

> test=1
>
> test2=2

if search string str="test2" is given then it should return value 2 .
Sample code i have tried is

```
public class ScannerExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
 
        //creating File instance to reference text file in Java
        
        String filePath = "c:/temp/test.txt";
        //Creating Scanner instnace to read File in Java
        
        String str = "text";
        //Reading each line of file using Scanner class
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(sCurrentLine.contains(str))  {
                result=true;
                System.out.println("Found entry ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

here I am check if value exists or not .please suggest some method to fetch its value

```
sample.txt:
test=1
test2=2
testnew=new
testold=old2
```

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Can you add information about test.txt or post it ? Does each pair (like test2=2) is listed in a separate line ?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto It was on separate lines only

Comment: yes in separate lines

Comment: plz chk information about test.txt edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a `Properties` object and load the file with it

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try (Reader reader = new FileReader(filePath)) {
    // Load the file
    p.load(reader);
}
// Print the value of the parameter test2
System.out.println(p.getProperty("test2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split and get the value.

```
String[] splits = sCurrentLine.split("=");
System.out.println("Value is " + splits[1])
```

and will contain the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in couple of ways:

**Way 1:**

Read File line by line and split each line by `=` and use left part as key and right part as value. Put them in a `HashMap`. While doing look up read it from HashMap on basis of key.

**Way 2:**

In your current approach, split each line by `=` and match entered key with left part if it matches return right part.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not change it that way. it was already written on two separate lines. i just formatted it. You should have look at question history before commenting.